# Given GCD and LCM of two numbers, find the lowest possible sum of them.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If it helps, GCD(a, b) = 10, LCM = 1494500.
There must be a few step algorithm, and the first step there is to find LCM/GCD = 149450 and I'm outta of ideas here, internet search is fruitless for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So

$10 = 2\cdot 5$ and

$1494500 = 2^2\cdot 5^3\cdot (7^2\cdot 61)$

Now $10$ divides both $a$ and $b$.

That mean $\frac {1494500}{10} = 2 \cdot 25 \cdot 49 \cdot 61$ must be divided between $a,b$ so that each term goes to one or the other.

Now.... experience and intuition and AM. GM inequality.

If we have $ab = M, a,b > 0$ and we want to minimize $a + b$ it should occur to us that the sum is the smallest when $a,b$ are closest together and the sums are the largest when the are for apart.  Experience with max/minimizing area and optimiztion problems should make that clear but we can prove it.

If $ab = M$ then $a=\sqrt M\cdot r$ and $b = \sqrt M\cdot \frac 1r$ and so $a+ b= \sqrt M (r + \frac 1r)$.  Wolog assume $r\ge 1$ and let $r = 1+e$ then $r + \frac 1r = 1 +e + \frac 1{1+e} = 1 + e + \frac {1+e - e}{1+e} = 1+e + 1 -\frac e{1+e} = 2 + (e-\frac e{1+e})$.  Now $1+e \ge 1$ so $e - \frac e{1+e} \ge 0$ with equality holding only if $e = 0$.  And the larger $e$ is the larger $e-\frac e{1+e}$ will be.

So the minimum sum is when $e$ is smallest and when $a$ and $b$ are closest together.

....

So we must must divy up $2, 25, 49, 61$ into two values as close as possible.

And the minimum of that is $2\cdot 61$ and $25\cdot 49$.

So $a = 2\cdot 61 \cdot 10$ and $b = 25\cdot 49 \cdot 10$ will be the least sum.

Answer (score 2):

We know that $$ab=\gcd(a,b)\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=2^3\cdot5^4\cdot7^2\cdot61$$

Since $\gcd(a,b)=10$ each of $a,$ must have a factor of $2$ and a factor of $5$, and we have to split the remaining $2\cdot5^2\cdot7^2\cdot61$ between them so as to give the smallest sum.

At a glance it looks like the way to to this is $2\cdot5^2\cdot7$ and $7\cdot61$ giving $885$, but I'll leave it to you to confirm or refute this.  (Fleablood has refuted it in a comment.)

Comment: Dang I found $61\cdot 5$ what a noob I am

Comment: @HereToRelax I see I dropped a $0$ from the LCM.  I'll have to check if that changes anything.

Comment: Huh, no I think I made the mistakes but idk

Comment: @HereToRelax What I had before was definitely wrong.  What I have now may be wrong also; I want to leave something for the OP to do, so I just put down my first guess.

Comment: Sure that sounds fine, I upvoted both answers since they all seemed reasonable.

Comment: Um... you can't break up $49$ to $7\cdot 7$ or else the $\gcd$ will but $70$.

Comment: @fleablood You're right.

Answer (score 1):

There is a formula, the GCD of $2$ numbers times the LCM of those $2$ numbers is the product of the two numbers. So, in this case, $ab = 14945000 = 2^3(5^4)(7^2)(61)$. Due to AM-GM inequality, the lowest sum comes when $a$ and $b$ are closest to each other. Since the GCD is $10$, both $a$ and $b$ have $2$ and $5$ as factors. Since the LCM is $1494500$, we know that that the number with the highest power for each prime factor of $14945000$, must have $2^2, 5^3, 7^2, 61$. This is the only way to achieve such a high LCM. Testing, we can see that $a = 2^2(5)(61)$ and $b = 2(5^3)(7^2)$ gives the smallest sum. So, the answer $= 1220 + 12250 = \boxed{13470}$

Comment: It seems there are some small mistakes.

Comment: @HereToRelax example?

Comment: I think the answer is $1220,1225$, I'm not exactly sure where it went wrong, but I'm sure the general idea is correct.

Comment: @HereToRelax I checked the LCM of 1220, 1225 and it is not 1494500, it is 298900.

Comment: Oh, well my bad sorry about that, I already upvoted you though.

Comment: @HereToRelax thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is fun. 
As discussed in the other responses, you have three constraints:

- gcd$(a,b) = 10.$
- $(a \times b) = (10 \times 1494500) = (100 \times 149450).$
- $a,b$ must be as close together as possible, to minimize the sum $(a + b).$

This means that $a,b$ must be expressed as 
$a = (10 \times r), ~b = (10 \times s)$ 
where $r,s$ are relatively prime and
$(r \times s) = (149450).$

You have that $149450 = (2^1 \times 5^2 \times 7^2 \times 61).$
This means that $a,b$ must be expressed as 
$a = (10 \times r), b = (10 \times s)$ 
where $r,s$ are relatively prime and
$(r \times s) = (2^1 \times 5^2 \times 7^2 \times 61).$

Because $(r,s)$ are relatively prime, you have that both prime factors of $5$ must go to either $r$ or $s$.  That is, you can **not** assign one of the prime factors $(5^1)$ to $r$ and the other prime factor $(5^1)$ to $s$.  Otherwise, $r,s$ would not be relatively prime, which would cause the gcd$(a,b)$ to be $> 10$, thus violating one of the constraints.  Similar considerations apply to the prime factors $(7^2)$.

Therefore, the challenge is to consider the 4 numbers of 
$(2), (5^2 = 25), (7^2 = 49),$ and $(61)$ as unbreakable **factor-units**. 
Each factor-unit must be assigned to one of $r,s$ such that $r,s$ end up being as *close together* as possible.

Examining the 4 factor-units, you see one

$$\textbf{candidate-partitioning} ~~\text{is}~~
r = (2 \times 61) = 122, ~s = (25 \times 49) = 1229.\tag1$$

From the above candidate-partitioning, you conclude that the two factor-units of $(61)$ and $(49)$ **must be separated**.

So the **starter-partitioning** is to place $(61)$ with $r$ and $49$ with $s$.

This leaves $4$ possible ways to complete the **required starter-partitioning**:

- $(2)$ goes to either $r$ or $s$, and
- $(25)$ goes to either $r$, or $s$.

Note that as a result of the required starter-partitioning, $s$ is (temporarily) approximately 80% as large as $r$.  This is because $(49)$ is approximately 80% of $(61).$  Because the two remaining factor-units $2$ and $25$ are each unbreakable, you must send the smaller factor-unit, $(2)$ to $(r)$ and the larger factor-unit, $(25)$ to $s$.

Therefore, the candidate-partitioning in (1) above, must be optimal. 
Therefore, the optimal values for $a,b$ are
$a = (10 \times 2 \times 61), ~b = (10 \times 25 \times 49).$